# Computer going to sleep while being used

Tags: windows-7, windows, keyboard, virus, sleep

i just got my laptop back from a service, one of the hinges broke and i had it replaced.

The problem now is that it keeps going to sleep while i'm using it(not that i'm running a program, i'm typeing and it goes to sleep).

I've checked the event viewer and what i get is "Sleep Reason: Button or Lid". My question is could thid be caused by a virus(is so how can i tell, it also happens when i input my password can a virus send the pc to sleep while the login screen is displayed) or did they just mess up the wireing and when i type something happens. Btw it only happens when i type.

Windows 7 Professional x64.

Asus N61JV.

Sorry for the quality of the question but i'm using my phone.

Comment: Just out of curiosity - why would a virus put your computer to the sleep mode? It would effectively prevent the virus from doing anything. What would be the point of such virus? That doesn't make a sense.

Comment: I would rather check the health of your battery. I know the reason in the Event log is *Button or Lid*, but maybe it's just because there's not enough capacity of the battery, so Windows puts the computer to the sleep mode to prevent data loss when the battery goes out of energy completely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Malware, which main purpose is to shut itself down from operating, is something I would put into the "yeah, possible but implausible" corner.

You can look into the `Event Viewer` of Windows to find out the reason for the shutdown / sleep: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/open-event-viewer#1TC=windows-7

> Open Event Viewer by clicking the Start button Picture of the Start
>   button, clicking Control Panel, clicking System and Security, clicking
>   Administrative Tools, and then double-clicking Event Viewer.‌ 
>   Administrator permission required If you're prompted for an
>   administrator password or confirmation, type the password or provide
>   confirmation.

It's more likely that your hardware does something funny: They keyboard not correct attached to the mainboard or some other malfaction.

Comment: I mentioned in my question the reason in EV is button or lid, but it's not that hard to add an entry to it, how can i tell if it's legit ?

Comment: It's not hard to add an event? How so?

Comment: Done that lots of times from code in C# for example, it does require admin rights thougb

Comment: Well, by that argument _everything_ is possible.